# Large celery overhead -- expected?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm experiencing large overhead when running a fast task using `celery` with `redis` as my backend and broker. The task takes around 5ms to complete as reported on flower's runtime, but the timestamps contain a large amount of overhead:

Sent: 2023-04-13 14:52:30.028880 UTC
Received: 2023-04-13 14:52:30.702813 UTC
Started: 2023-04-13 14:52:30.729512 UTC
Succeeded: 2023-04-13 14:52:31.163038 UTC

It seems as if there's a large bottleneck between sending and receiving, and between running and "succeeding". I timed the pickling of my task's arguments, and it only takes around 1ms, so I have largely eliminated that as a possibility.

I've tried switching to `rabbitmq` as a backend, but did not notice a substantial difference.